# How to increment timer in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

We are getting time in string value from server code to UI page(JSP page).
Time can be anything anything like 14:34:45 (HH:mm:ss)

We have to make it as a clock(increment by second) right from 14:34:45.
How to write javascript for this? We tried lot many solution but it is not moving.

Comment: Add your attempts in question

Comment: Have a look at my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need such jQuery or something to do. You can use simple JavaScript:

```js
setInterval(function () {
  d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = d.getHours();
  document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = d.getMinutes();
  document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = d.getSeconds();
}, 500);
```

```html
<span id="h"></span>:<span id="m"></span>:<span id="s"></span>
```

The `500` is the update interval. Lesser the interval, better the transition.

If you have a preset one, you can do it this way:

```js
d = new Date();
d.setHours(14);
d.setMinutes(25);
d.setSeconds(0, 0);
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = d.getHours();
  document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = d.getMinutes();
  document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = d.getSeconds();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="h"></span>:<span id="m"></span>:<span id="s"></span>
```